# How to and what tools do I use to cable between 3 floors at my house.

Tags: cabling, low-voltage, coaxial-cable

What tools do I need and what techniques do I use to to cable a cable (coax) between 3 floors.   Actually it's from my first floor of a two story home to the attic.

I have searched and searched and I can't find the answer.  I see flexible drill it extensions but nothing like a good 6 footer.

I want  to know from professionals what is used and any possible videos.  I am having problems because I think I have the wrong tools.  I keep loosing my drill bit extensions in the wall.

Comment: Are you intending to try and run this in the interior, versus a subtle, not-so visible exterior run? If you want to go through the interior, it's worth checking to see if you have any long plumbing runs, attic spaces, etc. Sometimes these can be a boon for making a long pull. Otherwise, you will probably end up cutting interior drywall where you runs terminate at different headers, studs, noggins, etc.

Comment: I agree with BrownRedHawk, the easiest method is to follow an existing chase.  A plumbing stack is a good candidate for a basement to attic chase.

Comment: If you value your time over aesthetics, just run the cable outside. Everybody else is.

Comment: They make extensions for the flexible installer bits. Just make sure you tighten them down tight. I like the klein extensions. I've lost bits in walls with other brands. Also might help if you grind down the end of the installer bit so it's not round. Or you can just cut out the drywall a little at the top and bottom of the wall and then repair it. This is a fairly complicated question to answer because there are different ways of doing it depending on your structure.

Answer (score 2):

As an update I wanted to let everyone know that I got the super long drill bit rods and extensions and made all of the ports myself.  I like hard wire to my stationary devices (tvs, media devices, and pcs) and I also like hard wiring WAPs so that I always have the best wifi coverage.

I ended up dropping almost 2k of car 6 in my house and 1200 feet of CCTV camera cable.

Enjoyed learning and thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run cable through your existing walls, there are powerline adaptors that allow you to pass internet via the electrical outlets in your home.

[Outlet Connectors](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/netgear-powerline-network-adapter-white/4320444.p)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I've removed the parts of your answer that don't answer the original question.